# Should I capitalise "or" between examples?

Tags: capitalization, convention

On this site, there are often many different options as an answer, for example both with and without the Oxford comma.

When giving multiple options, should I capitalize the word "or" between them?

Option 1:

> Eggs, butter and milk are dairy products
>   Or
>   Eggs, butter, and milk are dairy products

Option 2:

> Eggs, butter and milk are dairy products
>   or
>   Eggs, butter, and milk are dairy products

Notice in Option 1 the *"or"* is capitalised. In Option 2 the *"or"* isn't.

Comment: You are combining *phrases* rather than *sentences,*  I think lower case looks better.

Comment: Have you a reference for this usage of the noun 'dairy' (ie the abstract usage as opposed to the building)? I've never met it before, though 'nuclear' as in "Nuclear is more expensive than gas and oil" has achieved abstract noun status.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, offering two options, of which only one is meant to be chosen, takes a form like this:

> Do you prefer "A" or "B"?

In your example, A = "Eggs, butter and milk are dairy", and B = "Eggs, butter, and milk are dairy", so we'd get:

> Do you prefer "Eggs, butter and milk are dairy" or "Eggs, butter, and milk are dairy"?

which is closer to your second version.

However, because the difference here is just a single character, I think the most readable version is to use bullets:

> Which do you prefer:
>
> - "Eggs, butter and milk are dairy"; or
> - "Eggs, butter, and milk are dairy"