# Should I capitalize the middle of a sentence broken up by long examples?

Tags: capitalization, writing-style

In the context of a technical manual, I need to write instructions guiding users through several standard manipulations. When providing examples of these manipulations, I have written a short sentence containing "before" and "after" examples which appear in (potentially multi-line) vertical blocks of their own. As a result, I am unsure as to whether the middle of the sentence should be capitalized.

---

**With capitalization**

Hence, the following code:

```
camera.start_recording('foo.h264', quantization=25)
```

Should be replaced with:

```
camera.start_recording('foo.h264', quality=25)
```

---

**Without capitalization**

Hence, the following code:

```
camera.start_recording('foo.h264', quantization=25)
```

should be replaced with:

```
camera.start_recording('foo.h264', quality=25)
```

---

My instinct suggests the second example is preferable, but I'd be interested to learn of any rules surrounding this. For that matter, if there is a better way of structuring such examples which avoids the capitalization issue altogether, I would be most interested!

[Should I capitalise "or" between examples?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199088/should-i-capitalise-or-between-examples) was the most relevant question I could find to this one, and I tend to agree with its reasoning that the lowercase version is preferable. Unfortunately the best suggestion in its answer (to use a bullet list of examples) doesn't really lend itself to potentially large blocks of code.

Comment: I'd drop the colons (the block-highlighting does their job quite adequately) as well as the second capital.

Comment: I'll have to see if the authoring system I'm using (ReadTheDocs) permits removing the colons. It's based on the reStructuredText markup system which uses a terminating double-colon (rendered as a single colon) to indicate that the following block-quote is a literal block. There's probably a way, but I don't recall it off the top of my head! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, I think this question is Off Topic anyway. I don't see the layout of "code blocks" is a feature of *English* as addressed on ELU - it's *typesetting*, which might be a better fit on [SE TEX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You're trying to find middle ground between what the rules of English demand (and doubtless that's very dubious where punctuation around  block-quotes is involved) and what your system will allow. You really need someone familiar with both; system-specific constraints aren't part of English per se.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd agree with the typesetting part; does SE TeX support general type-setting questions? I thought it would be geared toward TeX-based systems (ReadTheDocs renders primarily to HTML, although it does use TeX for PDF output). I'm unsure about the duplicate part (but I'm happy for it to be closed as such - evidently lowercase is the consensus opinion)

Comment: I would think that this is more of a style choice and might get a better answer over at http://writers.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: Both the answer and one of the comments on the earlier question clearly imply that "mid sentence" capitalisation isn't a feature of standard written English. But I'd have thought the opinions of the guys at TEX would be worth seeking, in your situation.

Comment: @Hellion - ah! That definitely looks more appropriate (especially their technical-writing wiki tag) - I'd not encountered that corner of SE yet. Many thanks. Quick question of etiquette - would it be better to simply delete the question from here, or mark it duplicate?